# How Can I Install WebKit (Google Chrome) for Windows?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webkit

Recently I've started learning HTML and CSS, getting to nearly nail it now! But I have one issue. Im making a website based on a design i've seen somewhere before, and I need the title to be in a hollow font, like this:

[image]

Also i don't want to use an image for reasons to do with the layout of my page and stuff like that. So far i've managed to make the actual text transparent:

```
p, h1{
margin:0px; padding:0px; 
color: transparent;
}
```

But I haven't been able to add an outline to the text. From my research apparently there was a "outline" property but it has been removed in CSS3, which I should mention is the version of CSS that I'm using. So this leaves me with only one choice : **USE PLUGINS**

I should probably make it clear that i hate plugins, both in html and other languages, but i don't have much of a choice here. The one that seems to be the best for this is the WebKit plugin.

So my question is:

1. How do I install the WebKit plugin? and other plugins in general?
2. Is there a way that doesn't involve any outside material other than
   pure HTML5 and CSS3 to outline text, or create a hollow font like the one in 
   the image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is deprecated and won't work with most browsers, so I suggest you not to use it. You said you can't use images, but if you're able to use SVG's you could try this:

```html
<svg>
  <text x="0" y="50" id="0" xml:space="preserve" style="font-size:56px;fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:2px;font-family:sans-serif">some text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Actually i have an issue. The SVG is too small for the text i need. How can is resize it? It doesnt stretch to fit the text